# GRE Addition Rule of Probability / When to add or subtract probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

Q: p. 648 Manhattan Prep GRE 5lb Third Edition A: p. 659

The probability that Maria will eat breakfast on any given day is $.5$; the probability that Maria will wear a sweater on any given day is $.3$; the two probabilities are independent of each other.

Quantity A: The probability that Maria eats breakfast or wears a sweater

Quantity B: $.8$

Here is the books explanation:
"Quantity B is greater. The problem indicates that the events occur independently of each other. Therefore, in calculating Quantity A, the first step is to calculate the "Or" situation, but don't stop there. Adding $0.5 + 0.3 = 0.8$ double counts the occurrences when both events occur. To compensate, subtract out the probability of both events occurring in order to get rid of the "double counted" occurrences. Notice that this is a Quantitative Comparison. Because the $0.8$ figure includes at least one "both" occurrence, the real figure for Quantity A must be less than $0.8$. Therefore, Quantity B must be greater.To do the actual math, find the probability of both events occurring (breakfast and sweater): $0.5 \times 0.3 = 0.15$. Subtract the "and" occurrences from the total "or" probability: $0.8 - 0.15 = 0.65$. Thus, Quantity B is greater."

I went ahead and did $.5 \times .3=.15$ (Chance of no sweater and chance of breakfast) plus $.5 \times .7=.35$ (chance of sweater and no breakfast) = $.5$ and assumed that the 'or' statement from Quantity A excluded the probability of S and B simultaneously. The book seems to use the addition rule of probability in a way that could be faster in the context of a more complicated question, however I cannot make it make sense (not to mention this use of the addition rule applies to several questions in this chapter).

I do not understand the addition rule of probability or the double counting in this instance or why this question is not part of the 'special case' of the addition rule as explained in the video below. (The special case of the addition rule says to add the probabilities of two mutually exclusive events, the obvious crux being what if they add up to more than one?) Any help would be appreciated.

This video on youtube is the closest I can come to finding an explanation that matches that from the book:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vIu9x-jyBL8&ab_channel=ResearchByDesign

Comment: Not sure what is puzzling you.  In general, if $X, Y$ are two possible events, then the probability that at least one them occurs is $P(X)+P(Y)-P(X\cap Y)$.  In your case, $X\cap Y$ has positive probability.

Comment: "Here is the book's explanation: 'Quantity B is greater ...'" But no question about which quantity is greater has been mentioned.

Comment: „ and assumed that the 'or' statement from Quantity A excluded the probability of S and B simultaneously“ — this assumption is false, „A or B“ is true also if A and B are both true. What you are thinking of is an exclusive or, which is a different operation often named „xor“.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a lot. I'm not good at this

Comment: Right.  Definitely *NOT* an an exclusive or.  You would use an exclusive or when you are definately ruling out they can't both happen.  As these events are independent it is, of course, possible to eat breakfast *and* wear a sweater.  So no, exclusive or would not be relevant unless specifically asked for.

Comment: "(The special case of the addition rule says to add the probabilities of two mutually exclusive events, the obvious crux being what if they add up to more than one?)"  The key there being MUTUALLY EXCLUSIVE.  Wearing a Sweater and eating breakfast are certainly *not* mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are four distinct possibilities:

Breakfast and Sweater ($B \cap S$)
Breakfast and no Sweater ($B \cap \overline S$)
No Breakfast and a sweater ($\overline B \cap S$)
No Breakfast and no sweater. ($\overline B \cap \overline S$)

If you calculate them and add them the add to $1$.  B and S = $.5\times .3 = .15$.  B and no S= $.5\times .7 = .35$.  No B and S = $.5\times .3=.15$ and No B and no S = $.5\times .7 = .35$.

Tow wear eat breakfast or wear a sweater is to and B and S, B and no S, no B and S and that is $.15 + .35 + .15 = .65$.

Okay... but how to do it without having to break it down so far?

Well.  B and S combined with no B and S would be... to wear a sweater whether you ate breafast or not.  So $P(B\cap S) + P(\overline B\cap S) = P(S)$.

And we can do our probability by $P(B\cup S)=P(B\cap S) +P(\overline B\cap S)+ P(B\overline S)=$

$\underbrace{P(B\cap S) +P(\overline B\cap S)}+ P(B\cap\overline S)=$

$P(S) + P(B\cap\overline S)$.

But we could have just as easily combined $B \cap S$ and $B \cap \overline S$ to get the cases where breakfast is eaten whether or not a sweater is worn.

$P(B\cup S)=P(B\cap S) + P(B\overline S)+P(\overline B\cap S)=$

$\underbrace{P(B\cap S) + P(B\cap\overline S)}+P(\overline B\cap S)=$

$P(B) + P(\overline B\cap S)$....

But both of these ways are too hard.

Notice that we have $P(B) = P(B\cap \overline S) + P(B\cap S)$.

And $P(S) = P(\overline B \cap S) + P(B \cap S)$.

If we add them together (why? because we've had a few drinks and its friday night and we want to see what would happen) we get

$P(B) + P(S) = P(B\cap \overline S) +P(\overline B \cap S) + 2P(B\cap S)$.

We have counted $B\cap S$ *twice*.  Which is *not* surprising as $B\cap S$ is including in *both* $B$ and $S$.

If we subtract one of the $P(B\cap S)$ to adjust for this "double counting" we get.

$P(B) + P(S) - P(B\cap S) = P(B\cap \overline S) +P(\overline B \cap S) + P(B\cap S)$

But the RHS is all the cases of B *or* C.

So $P(B\cup S) = P(B) + P(S) - P(B\cap S)$.

....

But does that make sense?

Of course it does.

To calculate whether $B$ or $S$ occur we consider that $B$ occurs both with $S$ and without $S$.  And we consider that $S$ occurs both with $B$ and without $B$.  But in combining this we are cansidering $B$ with $S$ both and total of two times when we should only consider them once!  So.... just subtract one of them

Answer (score 0):

> ... assumed that the 'or' statement from Quantity A excluded the
> probability of S and B simultaneously.

This lies at the core of your problem here. "Or" implies that *at least one* of the events must be true.

For the stated question, it covers the following.

1. Maria has breakfast but does not wear a sweater. $P(X) = 0.5 \times 0.7 = 0.35$
2. Maria does not have a breakfast but wears a sweater. $P(Y) = 0.5 \times 0.3 = 0.15$
3. Maria has breakfast and wears a sweater too. $P(Z) = 0.5 \times 0.3 = 0.15$

So, the total probability $P = 0.35 + 0.15 + 0.15 = 0.65$.

> I do not understand ... why this question is not part of the
> 'special case' of the addition rule as explained in the video below.

This question is part of the "special case" (in this context). We just added the individual probabilities to get the probability of the union. But as explained above, you left out one case that must be added too.

> The special case of the addition rule says to add the probabilities of
> two mutually exclusive events, the obvious crux being what if they add
> up to more than one?

They will never add up to more than one. Let me give you an example.

Say, $n$ is the total number of outcomes possible for an experiment. And, say, events $E_1$ and $E_2$ are two *mutually exclusive* events. Also, $E_1$ can happen in $n_1$ ways and $E_2$ in $n_2$ ways.

Now using the *addition rule*, the probability of $E_1$ OR $E_2$ happening would be

$$\begin{align*}
P(E_1 \cup E_2) &= P(E_1) + P(E_2) \\[0.3cm]
&= \frac{n_1}{n} + \frac{n_2}{n} \\[0.3cm]
&= \frac{n_1 + n_2}{n}
\end{align*}$$

Now, ask yourself. Can $n_1 + n_2$ ever be greater than $n$? Remember $n$ is the total number of outcomes. $n_1$ and $n_2$ represent only disjoint parts of that total.

Can parts cut out of a single pizza ever add up to more than the pizza?